# Three.js / Rotate object around its' Y-axis to look in particular direction

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js

I tried to wrap my head around it for at least a week, but it's too heavy for me.
The problem is that when I click on particular coordinates on the PLANE, i want my 3d model to rotate to face the new coordinates, and then change it's position to match the new coordinates ( it would be nice if you also explain to me how to declare objects' speed and move it with that speed ).

I know it has to do something with THREE.Matrix4() function.

*(If You ever played starcraft or similar game, you'll know what I'm up to ;> )*

**Here is what I have so far:**

http://f.cl.ly/items/1u2q463D1Y0K3G1W2g3P/bf.jpg

**And here is what I want to achieve:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2vrs.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will need to do raycasting, to calculate the position of the plane that your mouse cursor intersected when you clicked, check out http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Mouse-Over.html for a related example with code. Then, once you know the position, you can use the `lookAt` function: see http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/misc_lookat.html for details.

Comment: yes, but can I animate the whole procedure of rotation, and then the 2 question is: How to declare objects speed and animate it to certain position with constant speed ?

Comment: For animation you might want to look at Tween.js -- see http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/08/17/tweenjs-for-smooth-animation/ for an introduction.